# How to make a new command similar to \author

Tags: memoir, titles

I'm preparing a new template for our students' projects based on `memoir`. All this projects are supervised (directed) by one or more professors so I would like to declare a command like `\author` but called `\director`.

This way the student can declare `\director{My professor}` and the template will place and format the name.

I would like to be like `\author` and not just a simple `\newcommand` because it can include affiliation, several names, etc.

I don't know where is `\author` declared, where should I look?

Comment: Be specific over the placement of the new `\director` location. It's easy to find where `\author` is defined/declared (in [`memoir.cls`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/memoir.dtx))

Comment: How about `\let\author\director`? This will make the command `\director` inherit/receive all properties of the `\author` command -- how ever the latter command is set up.

Comment: then `\director{foo}` will overwrite the author setting.

Comment: @Werner Previous to my question I looked for `\author` and `\@author` definitions in `memoir.cls`. `\author` appears in lines 2493 and 2525 but there is no definition there. And `\@author` is used in `\maketitle` (lines 2449-2465). Looking there more carefully I've understood how to declare and insert a `\director` command into `\maketitle`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As mentioned, `\author` and `\@author` are defined in [`latex.ltx`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/unpacked/latex.ltx), but [`memoir`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir) adds some extra flair to them (for example, allowing multiple authors via `\and` and properly setting them). The following minimal example adds `\director` to the mix:

[image]

```
\documentclass{memoir}% http://ctan.org/pkg/memoir
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\director}[1]{\gdef\@director{#1}}%
\newcommand{\@director}{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\director given}}
\addtoiargdef{\director}{%
  \begingroup\let\footnote\@gobble}{%
  \begingroup
    \renewcommand{\thanks}[1]{}
    \renewcommand{\and}{\unskip, }
    \renewcommand{\andnext}{\unskip, }
    \renewcommand{\thanksmark}[1]{}
    \renewcommand{\thanksgap}[1]{}
    \protected@xdef\thedirector{#1}
  \endgroup\endgroup}
\newcommand{\predirector}[1]{\def\@bspredirector{#1}}
\newcommand{\postdirector}[1]{\def\@bspostdirector{#1}}
\renewcommand{\maketitlehookc}{%
  {\@bspredirector \@director \@bspostdirector}%
}
\predirector{\begin{center}
  \large \lineskip .5em%
  \begin{tabular}[t]{c}}
\postdirector{\end{tabular}\par\end{center}}
\makeatother
\title{A Title}
\author{An Author \and Another Author}
\director{My Director \and My other Director}
\date{\today}
\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

The process is a duplication of the components of `\author` and inserts the `\director` below the `\author` inside `\@maketitle` using the hooks provided. That is, `\@maketitle` has a hook:

- `\maketitlehooka` before `\title`;
- `\maketitlehookb` before `\author`;
- `\maketitlehookc` before `\date`; and
- `\maketitlehookd` after `\date`.

I've redefined `\maketitlehookc` to now be/contain `\director` and it is formatted in the same way `\author` is (`center`ed and `\large`).

Comment: Can this be used in an article? How? I tried to change `memoir` with `article` but it won't work.

Comment: How can I do the same thing in a `report` class document?

Comment: @Kajsa: You want *exactly* the same in `report`?

Comment: @Werner: I am building my own `\maketitle` in a customized `report` class and I want to add a `\supervisor` option that will work as `\author` and only be shown if a supervisor is set.

Comment: @Kajsa: Here is a simple way to insert a `\supervisor`: [Code](http://pastebin.com/4UmPuijp). It's simple because it assumes a specific order of the title commands: `\supervisor` *after* `\author`, and appends the supervisor content to the `\@author` macro which is set during `\maketitle`. This code also works with/without `titlepage` option. Alternatively, this code uses [`etoolbox`](http://ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox) to patch `\@maketitle` and insert `\@supervisor` directly: [Code](http://pastebin.com/C8W4axzV). Therefore, order of usage doesn't matter. Update required for non-`titlepage` usage.

Comment: @Werner: Thank you. But for some reason the `\ifcsname` does not seem to work. If I do not define `\supervisor` the document does not compile. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: @Kajsa: What are you compiling with? Perhaps you could post some code that I can work with. Alternatively, [ask a follow-up question here](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/2117/5764).

Comment: @Werner: I have tried TeXMaker `PDFLaTeX` and `LaTeX`. It gives the error `undefined control sequence`. Here's a minimum example [Code](http://pastebin.com/kh7gkQAL).

Comment: @Kajsa: There's no need to `\patchcmd{\maketitle}` when you're just going to redefine `\maketitle` immediately after it. Here's some code that compiles fine on my end: [Code](http://pastebin.com/gvpmgc56)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49900/discussion-between-kajsa-and-werner).

Answer (score 13):

`author` is defined in `latex.ltx`

```
\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{#1}}
\def\@author{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\author given}}
```

you can load the file under Linux with

```
gedit `kpsewhich latex.ltx`
```

However, `memoir` has some more definitions of authors. Have a look into the file `memoir.cls` and search for author. In the title the macro `\@author` is used and set to `\relax` after the title.