# Print macro content with condition

Tags: macros, conditionals

I would like something like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\acell}{}
\newcommand{\bcell}
\newccomand{\zcell}[1]{#1}
\ifx\acell{A}
 \ifx\bcell{A}
  \zcell{yes}
 \else
  \zcell{no}
 \fi
\else
\fi
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\acell{A} & \bcell{A} & \zcell{} \\
\acell{A} & \bcell{B} & \zcell{} \\  
\end{document}
```

But this code does not work. It does not print "yes" and "no" where the 'zcell' macro is.
Is it possible to achieve this?

Comment: Yes, it is, but under which rules? Besides the errors pointed out by David Carlisle, the conditions aren’t even inside a command but just in the preamble (and `\newccomand` is mis-typed). Do you want to test both cells whether they are `A`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question isn't very clear (and your example is very incomplete) but I think you want

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand{\acell}[1]{\gdef\acontent{#1}#1}
\newcommand{\bcell}[1]{\gdef\bcontent{#1}#1}
\def\atest{A}
\newcommand{\zcell}{%
\ifx\acontent\atest
 \ifx\bcontent\atest
  yes%
 \else
  no%
 \fi
\else
  no%
\fi}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\acell{A} & \bcell{A} & \zcell \\
\acell{A} & \bcell{B} & \zcell 
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

some notes on your example

```
\newcommand{\acell}{}
```

defines `\acell` to take no arguments and expand to nothing but you were using it as if it took an argument.

```
\newcommand{\bcell}
```

is a syntax error (you haven't provided a definition at all)

```
\newccomand{\zcell}[1]{#1}
```

just defines `\zcell` to echo its argument.

```
\ifx\acell{A}
```

is not in any definition and compares the token `\acell` to the token `{` then skips to the matching `\fi` as those tokens are not equal.

Comment: You add a picture :-) -- Should I add one too.

Answer (score 5):

You can do the following whereby I don't know what you want to achieve:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\makeatletter
\def\acell#1{\gdef\@acell{#1}}
\def\bcell#1{\gdef\@bcell{#1}}
\def\zcell{%
 \ifx\@acell\@bcell
     yes\acell{a}\bcell{b}%
 \else
   no
 \fi%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{ccc}
\acell{A} & \bcell{A} & \zcell{} \\
\acell{A} & \bcell{B} & \zcell{} \\  
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Some other hints:

- The material of a table cell is always local. So `\gdef` is needed.
- [What does \ifx\\#1\\ stand for?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33823/what-does-ifx-1-stand-for/33826#33826) -- Explained `\ifx`
- [How to make a new command similar to \author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58506/how-to-make-a-new-command-similar-to-author/58528#58528) -- explained the definition of `\acell`