# How to add new macros like \author{} without editing latex.ltx

Tags: documentclass-writing

I want to write a new class based on the article class for student home-works that needs a modified title page.

### Is it possible to create new macros like \title{} and \author{} that can be used in the modified \maketitle code (e.g. \tutor{} and \dueDate{}) without editing the latex.ltx file?

In the question [How to make a new command similar to \author](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58506/how-to-make-a-new-command-similar-to-author) the class that is worked on is memoir.cls while I'm trying to modify the article.cls. Furthermore the best solution given is by adding new information to \author macro and not on how to add new macros that are ready to use in the preamble.

Comment: see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/58506/how-to-make-a-new-command-similar-to-author

Comment: They are using the memoir class there while I'm trying to do this by modifying the article.cls.

Comment: Also they don't really answer the question. And in the comments it is hinted that information can be added to the \author macro but not how to create a new one

Comment: Yes that is possible and you should indeed not modify `latex.ltx` at all. It will probably come down to copying the relevant bits from `article.cls`/`latex.ltx` and elsewhere and adding the redefinition to your custom class.

Comment: The linked answer shows how to define a command analogous to `\author`, namely `\director`: `\newcommand{\director}[1]{\gdef\@director{#1}}%
\newcommand{\@director}{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\director given}}`. You can now use `\@director` in your title formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `latex.ltx`, there are two lines related to `\author`:

```
\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{#1}}
\def\@author{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\author given}}
```

Then you can always have

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\def\tutor#1{\gdef\@tutor{#1}}
\def\@tutor{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\tutor given}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\tutor{Al Fh}
\makeatletter\@tutor\makeatother
\end{document}
```

Now customize your `\maketitle` with this command `\@tutor`, like

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\makeatletter
\def\tutor#1{\gdef\@tutor{#1}}
\def\@tutor{\@latex@warning@no@line{No \noexpand\tutor given}}
\renewcommand\maketitle{%
\begin{center}
\textbf{\Huge\@title}\\[2em]
{\large\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}ll}
    Author: & \@author\\
    Tutor: & \@tutor\\
    Date: & \@date
\end{tabular}}
\end{center}\par\vspace{2em}}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\title{My document}
\author{Your student}
\tutor{Al Fh}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\lipsum[1]
\end{document}
```

Comment: So in the end I have to define \tutor after the begin{document} label and not before it?

Comment: @Al_Fh No. You can put `\tutor` in the preamble if you like. I prefer putting it inside.